# How do you assign each word in an inputted sentence a number?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program that assigns each word in a sentence a number (or position). But if the word occurs again, its number is the same as it first occurred.
For example:
If I inputted the sentence "My cat loves cheese and loves cake", it should output "1,2,**3**,4,5,**3**,7". Since "loves" occurred twice, it is the same number as it was the first time

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us your code? Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: This is the problem. I'm only a beginner and have looked for something but I haven't found anything yet. I have a while loop for the input of the sentence but it's the assigning part I'm useless at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [`list.index()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to find first occurrence of element in the list as:

```
>>> my_string =  "My cat loves cheese and loves cake"
>>> word_list = my_string.split()

#     As index starts with `0`, add 1  v
>>> ','.join(str(word_list.index(word)+1) for word in word_list)
'1,2,3,4,5,3,7'
```

Comment: Is it possible to put this into a file instead of the shell?

Comment: Everything is possible. The value you got is string. store the value in variable and write the string to file.

Comment: I've done it, thank you so much :)